# In experiments of 2-by-2 games where the dominant action benefits both players, do people frequently choose the other action?

Tags: game-theory, behavioral-economics, experimental-economics

Sayers et al look in [Some descriptive aspects of two-person non-zero-sum](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/002200276000400204?casa_token=2Tu4lDl7sxoAAAAA:hZAPPiOyqZmfCINGNs8a-zu1O-1vA4oXu4JJ3MD1XTwywyNaeNuPs6AJyXIeToTNePHyczLcfBVsLQ) games at variations of the prisoner dilemma. They had two participants (α and β) pressing press either a black (1) or a red (2) button. In one example they used the matrix:
[image]

In the discussion they write:

> In none of these games does the collaborative strategy, (α:1 and β:1)
> or black-black, occur more frequently than it would if subjects
> pressed red and black at random with equal probability.

Is this finding replicated in other studies or is it only a non-replicateable one-of-finding? In case there was a replication and it was better then random, did still a significant number of participants chose against picking the collaborative option?

Comment: How about calling this a 2-by-2 game instead of a prisoner's dilemma?

Comment: @Giskard : If you have a better idea how to formulate the question, I'm happy for you to edit it into a better form.

Comment: I remember having seen a similar game being called the *harmony game*, but I'm not aware of experimental studies.